# DB admin software that can block certain query

Tags: database, mysql

I need to know if there exists a database administration software for MySQL which have the following features

```
1. Can have multiple connections to multiple db servers
2. Then, I can block any kind of data modification query to a specific connection 
which can cause data loss such as DROP, DELETE, TRUNCATE and so on.
```

Basically, the permission can be controlled on the software-level instead of database-level.

I know we can just set up a user to have different privileges. 
The problem is i have only one database user given to me which have all the privileges.

currently, I'm using SQLYog. Sometimes, my task required me to switch between both production server DB and my local DB connection which could be confusing sometime and I'm afraid
one day I could accidentally execute something that I'm not supposed to execute like DROP and DELETE
is it probably possible to block myself from executing such destructive query from SQLYog? or is there a software which can do this?

Comment: "` The problem is i have only one database user given to me which have all the privileges`" - including the privilege of creating new, less-privileged users ;-)

Comment: @Mawg yes i can create new user. but its a complicated story. basically, creating new user is not an option